# Firebase update only given fields

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore, I have got some documents that represent forum posts for the project that I am developing with firebase functions and typescript.

The firestore structure looks like this:

```
{
    forumPosts: {
        :forumPostId: {
        
            id: string,
            content: string,
            icon: string,
            ...
        
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd want to allow the user to update his post. The body of the query should contain only the fields that need to be updated: let's say I'd want to update the content of my post, the query body should look like this:

```
{
    content: "updated content"
}
```

The firebase function that currently handles the updating looks like this.

```
export const updateNewForumPost=functions.https.onRequest((req: PR_UserRequest, res: Response) => {

    const fieldsToUpdate = {
        id: req.body.id,
        content: req.body.content,
        icon: req.body.icon,
        ...
    }

    db.collection("forumPosts").doc(req.params.postId).update( fieldsToUpdate )
        .then(() => {
            res.json({ message: `forum post ${req.params.postId} updated successfully` })
        })
        .catch((error) => res.json({ error }))

});
```

So I put in the "fields to update" object every field that the forumPost has, and inevitably the query has a lot of fields with old values that don't need to be updated.

As I said I am trying to find a way to put in that object only the fields that the user put in his request.
Any idea of how I should work with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? So: when you step through this code in a debugger, which line doesn't do waht you expect it to do?

Comment: There isn't a real problem. The point is that in the post object, there are a lot of fields that can be updated, like the content, the title, and many more. If the user wants to update only one of them, let's say the content, I should make a query with the updated content, and all the other fields with the old values. This is super tricky for me, especially if the object is big, like in this case.

Comment: Your `fieldsToUpdate` only need to contain the fields that you want to update. Passing in fields that aren't changed is just a waste of bandwidth. So how about only adding each field to `fieldsToUpdate` once you know that the user changed its value?